# Defining a variable member of a namespace outside the scope of the namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Where in the C++ Standard, does it say that the way to define a variable member of a namespace outside the scope of the namespace, is through the use of the `extern` specifier in the declaration of the variable member?

§3.4.1/14 mentions this "en passant":

> If a variable member of a namespace is defined outside of the scope of
>   its namespace then any name that appears in the definition of the
>   member (after the declarator-id) is looked up as if the definition of
>   the member occurred in its namespace. [ Example:

```
namespace N {
int i = 4;
extern int j;
}
int i = 2;
int N::j = i; // N::j == 4
```

Comment: **3.1/2** explains how an `extern` is a way to make a variable declaration that is not also a definition. This applies regardless of which namespace this declaration occurs, whether global or otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **3.1/2** A declaration is a definition unless ... it contains the `extern` specifier (7.1.1)...

`extern` has nothing to do with namespaces - it's just a way to make a variable declaration that is not also a definition. You are then free to choose to provide a separate definition either within or outside the namespace.